# C# Permissions and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I know that my main thread has certain permissions (specifically permissions to access the event log),

Will any threads I create in my application also have the same permissions?

i.e.

Do permissions **propogate** across threads?

Comment: SecurityContext is part of the thread's ExeuctionContext, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951924/excecutioncontext-of-threads/1952142#1952142

Answer (score 0):

No,The impersonation token does not propagate across threads , you need to obtain it for every thread you starting