# Why and when would I use AsyncFlowControl? And when should I not use it?

Tags: .net, multithreading, async-await

The [documentation for AsyncFlowControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asyncflowcontrol?view=net-5.0) says what it is.

But:

- What problem does it solve?
- When should I use it?
- When should I not use it?
- What are the common traps with using it?

Any relationship with ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow() is not clear unless a person already knows the answer to this question, hence I don't consider the question about ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow() to be a helpful duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ExecutionContext of Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951924/executioncontext-of-threads)

Comment: [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/logisimo/a-potentially-helpful-C-Sharp-threading-manual/) is a page with a sample program that uses the struct. It appears to be when one thread wants another one to wait until it's done?

Comment: To your edit - the struct is only used for SuppressFlow - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs,e8f2d39a353d043f,references

Comment: Check the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asyncflowcontrol?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: And this is not directly related to `async-await`.